# Add Item To kendoDropDownList

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I am trying to add a item to the kendoDropDownList, it seems to add the option but not set the value and text. Inspecting the select it just adds a new option

```
 <option></option>
```

Here is what I am using

```
 $("#nameList").data("kendoDropDownList")
     .dataSource.add({ "text": "Joe", "value": "Joe" });
```

UPDATE

Here is my datasource model and the `requestEnd` as suggested but the values seem to get messed up

```
datasource_people = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        type: "json",
        serverFiltering: true,
        transport: {
            read: {
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/restful/people/'
            }
        },
        filter: {
            field: "status",
            operator: "eq",
            value: 1
        },
        schema: {
            data: function(response) {
                return response.data.plaintiffs;
            },
            model: {
                id: "person_id",
                fields: {
                    person_id: {type: "number"},
                    name: { type: "string"}
                }
            },
            errors: "error",
            total: function(response) {
                return response.data.total;
            }
        }
    });
```

Then Later

```
$("#people_list").kendoDropDownList({
                    dataTextField: "text",
                    dataValueField: "value",
                    dataSource: {
                        datasource_people,
                        requestEnd: function (e) {
                            e.response.push({text: "John", value: "John"});
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After some searching it was quite simple but this worked for exactly what i needed.

```
$("#people_list").getKendoDropDownList().dataSource.insert({
    person_id: "John",
    name: "John"
})
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add a new item to the datasource after it has been loaded using [requestEnd](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#events-requestEnd).

```
requestEnd: function (e) {
  e.response.push({text: "Joe", value: "Joe"});
}
```

I've updated the other user's fiddle to show you it works.  [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/bWs9j/227/)

Comment: This seems to work and is more a long the lines of what i need, but for some reason all of the values and text display as 'undefined' only when selected. Strange.

Comment: An up vote or mark as answered would be great since it solves your problem.  You can post another question with the 'undefined' problem.

Comment: btw, your dataTextField and dataValueField fields are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<input id="nameList" value="1" />
var data = [
    { text: "Joe", value: "Joe" },
    { text: "Joe", value: "Joe"  },
    { text: "Joe", value: "Joe"  }
];

// create DropDownList from input HTML element
$("#nameList").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    dataSource: data,
    index: 0,         
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bWs9j/224/)

Comment: Thanks, but I should have mentioned that I already have options loaded in the list. This method would clear all of my current options rather than append to the list.

Comment: How could I call my original datasource along with the new data? transport: {
            read: {
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/restful/companies'
            }
        }

Comment: You can push in data new data, And after run again thus script

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you want, but you can load options from a datasource, and then append more to the list after `dataBound` has fired.

```
$("#nameList").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    dataSource: {
        transport: { 
            read: { 
                dataType: 'json', 
                type: 'GET', 
                url: '/restful/companies' 
            }
        } 
    },
    dataBound:onDataBound
});

<script>
    function onDataBound(e) {
        e.sender.dataSource.add({ "text": "Joe", "value": "Joe" });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: We're using the data- attributes to initialize the drop down. I can't find any information on a data- attribute for dataBound

Comment: I also tried this but does not seem to work:
function onDataBound(e) {
     e.sender.dataSource.add({ text: "John", value: "John" });
    }
    
    var dropdownlist = $("#nameList").data("kendoDropDownList");
    dropdownlist.bind("dataBound", onDataBound);